# jQuery FullCalendar select next day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Using the jQuery plugin [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), I want the selected date on the calendar to be incremented(by only one day) on a button `click` event.

This is the code I have been trying using the [`incrementDate()`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/incrementDate/) method:

```
$('#coolButton').click(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', 0, 0, 1);
});
```

This will only work if I increment the year or the month, but never if I increment the day. Any idea how to get the calendar to select the next day?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by increment day

Comment: @ArunPJohny for example, if the selected date was March 26th, 2014(3/26/2014), I want to click a button and change the selected date to March 27th, 2014(3/27/2014). The above method is supposed to do this but isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually It does increase the selected date by a given amount of time. (in your example by a single day). The thing is you can't see it.

if you click that button may be 30+ times you can see the calender will move to the next month. 
(If you change the CSS of the selected date, then you can see it increment)

Comment: Oh wow :P Well that explains things. But is there a way to just have all of the above features done automatically? As in have the next selected day along with CSS be moved to the next day. It is manageable as is, but having it done automatically would be nice.

Comment: I don't think there is a feature like that. :) But surely it's worth to add.